# NPM package quality with release views in VSTS-TFS

Tags: tfs, npm, azure-devops, package

I just read this [article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/feeds/views) which describes how to use Views in TFS Package Feeds for NuGet. I just wonder. if it also supports NPM packages? I did not find a way how to specify a view I want to use, while installing a NPM package. I can install any package, regardless it was promoted to a specific view.

Comment: Views do work with npm packages. Skorunka's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change URL in your ".npmrc" file to include a @View name.

**GUI**

Go to "*Connect to feed*" dialog, select "*npm*" from left menu and in the "*View*" selector, select your feed. Copy the text and insert it into your .npmrc file.

**Manual**

```
registry=https://seyc.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/**FEED_NAME**@**VIEW_NAME**/npm/registry
always-auth=true
```

Comment: The issue with Views is that you can not set permissions there. So anyone can actually download packages from @PreRelease. The solutions is to have two independent Feeds. On Feed you can set permissions.